# Android Activity Slow transition

Tags: android, android-intent, stack, transition

I want to remove the old activity from stack after clicking on a button that triggers an intent to a new activity.
The problem is: The transition is not smooth like a normal transition. For like a half second the screen is completely white.
How to make this smooth?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `Activity.overridePendingTransition().` 
Define simple transition animations with XML file.

Remmember this 4 atributes:

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
 android:toAlpha="1.0"
 android:duration="2000"
```

This atributtes make "smooth" transition

Comment: makes no difference

Answer (score -1):

Apps like `Google I/O 2014` use the following code to make transition between activities smooth.

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

You have to add it to both the *Base Activity* and the *Activity which is going to open*.

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX detail more on what is happening when you add that

Comment: Its the same behavior like without. I added the line after startAcitvity(). Then for like a half second the screen is white. After that the other activity shows up.

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX You have to add this line **in** the first line of `onCreate()` methods of both HomeActivity and MainActivity

Comment: makes no difference

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX try calling `finish()` after the `startActivity()`